# jqgrid onselected row redirect url not working on server (MVC3)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

i am having a problem with jqgrid onselected row event and document.location.href in MVC..

i have this code in my jqgrid:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    document.location.href ="/Search/Details/" + id;
                },
```

on selecting a row it will redirect to another view..its working fine on my machine..

whenever i pushed to server its not working there and its throwing page not found error..

can i use @Url.Content or some thing which resolves my url..or is there any server setting i need to look at...
please help me...thanks a lot...

UPDATE & Answer:
finally i found it..if we want to use @Url.Content check the following code..its working fine...

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    document.location.href ='@Url.Content("/Search/Details/")' + id;
                },
```

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) instead, since that is the relative path.

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
    window.location.pathname = "/Search/Details/" + id;
},
```

Comment: mofle thanks for your reply...its not working..I checked the page source and its showing all other links with the current url...because its using @Url.Content..but not the one i mentioned above..if can do a @Url.Content for above link my problem will be solved..can i do a @Url.content...